# Fragment with separated swipes from tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, android-tabs

I want to create 2 tabs ( Tab1, Tab2)
But in tab1 I want swipes like
Click (tab1)
Frag1.1 --> Frag1.2 --> Frag1.3
Click (tab2)
Frag2.1 --> Frag2.2 --> Frag2.3

How can I do this? I can't find any tutorial about this only tabs+swipes. Can you guys help me?

Should I get 2 Fragment Adapters? 
I'm trying to user 2 fragment adapters and setting like this, but I get an error "Fragment is not currently in the Fragment manager".

Any ideas?

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;
    public Context context;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
        {
            /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
            pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            //ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }
        else
        {
            /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
            pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter2);

        }
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that what you want are viewpagers inside each tab

Comment: thank you for your comment, i try that too but when i swipe to much sometimes doens't erase the fragment1 and then i get nullpointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bitbucket.org/ratz/tabtut/src

here it is my code for some help

**SOLVED** if you guys wanna check my program is right there. It's kinda "noobish" tho